# Seleccionar registros según correlativos

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Tengo el siguiente resultado de una query:

```
    BLOQUE  FECHA_INGRESO           DESDE       HASTA
    1       23-marzo-2017 08:25:37  08:20:00    09:00:00
    2       23-marzo-2017 08:25:37  09:01:00    09:40:00
    5       23-marzo-2017 08:25:37  11:20:00    12:00:00
    6       23-marzo-2017 08:25:37  12:01:00    12:40:00
```

Para este ejemplo, sólo debo seleccionar los primeros 2 registros ya que sus números de bloques son consecutivos( 1 y 2 ) y entre los siguientes ( 5 y 6 ) faltan el 3 y 4. Pero si los 4 registros tuvieran una numeración correlativa entre todos ellos, ejemplo 1,2,3 y 4, debo seleccionarlos todos.

No doy con la forma de hacerlo, alguna idea para lograrlo?

Desde ya, muchas gracias

**Actualización 31-07-2017:**

Gracias por responder.

Me di cuenta que cuando redacté la pregunta inicial, me faltó indicar algo muy importante.
Trataré de explicar de la mejor manera posible el problema que tengo:

Primero que todo, aquí dejo el create del ejemplo:

```
    CREATE TABLE INGRESOS(
        BLO_NUMERO          NUMBER,
        BLO_FECHA_INGRESO           DATE,
        BLO_DESDE           VARCHAR2(5),
        BLO_HASTA           VARCHAR2(5),
        BLO_FECHA_HASTA             DATE
    );

    INSERT INTO INGRESOS (BLO_NUMERO, BLO_FECHA_INGRESO, BLO_DESDE, BLO_HASTA, BLO_FECHA_HASTA)
    VALUES (1, TO_DATE('23/03/2017 8:25:37', 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'), '08:20:00', '09:00:00', TO_DATE('23/03/2017 9:00:00', 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'));
    INSERT INTO INGRESOS (BLO_NUMERO, BLO_FECHA_INGRESO, BLO_DESDE, BLO_HASTA, BLO_FECHA_HASTA) 
    VALUES (2, TO_DATE('23/03/2017 8:25:37', 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'), '09:01:00', '09:40:00', TO_DATE('23/03/2017 9:40:00', 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'));
    INSERT INTO INGRESOS (BLO_NUMERO, BLO_FECHA_INGRESO, BLO_DESDE, BLO_HASTA, BLO_FECHA_HASTA)
    VALUES (5, TO_DATE('23/03/2017 8:25:37', 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'), '11:20:00', '12:00:00', TO_DATE('23/03/2017 12:00:00', 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'));
    INSERT INTO INGRESOS (BLO_NUMERO, BLO_FECHA_INGRESO, BLO_DESDE, BLO_HASTA, BLO_FECHA_HASTA)
    VALUES (6, TO_DATE('23/03/2017 8:25:37', 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'), '12:01:00', '12:40:00', TO_DATE('23/03/2017 12:40:00', 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'));
```

Este sería el resultado del select a la tabla INGRESOS:

```
    BLO_NUMERO  BLO_FECHA_INGRESO       BLO_DESDE   BLO_HASTA   BLO_FECHA_HASTA
    1           23-03-2017 08:25:37 08:20:00    09:00:00    23-03-2017 09:00:00
    2           23-03-2017 08:25:37 09:01:00    09:40:00    23-03-2017 09:40:00
    5           23-03-2017 08:25:37 11:20:00    12:00:00    23-03-2017 12:00:00
    6           23-03-2017 08:25:37 12:01:00    12:40:00    23-03-2017 12:40:00
```

La problemática es la siguiente:

1.- Según la fecha de ingreso: 23-03-2017 08:25:37, debo seleccionar los bloques a los que "pertence" esa fecha y para este caso sólo serían los bloques 1 y 2, 
ya que existe un "hueco" entre los bloques 2 y 5.

2.- Si la fecha de ingreso fuera: 23/03/2017 11:25:37, sólo debo seleccionar los bloques 5 y 6.

3.- Si los número de bloques fueran continuos, es decir: 1, 2, 3 y 4 y la fecha de ingreso es: 23-03-2017 08:25:37, debo seleccionar los 4 registros ya que 
éstos son bloques consecutivos y no existen "huecos" entre los bloques.

Espero haber explicado de manera correcta la problemática.

Gracias.

Comment: podrias agregar un create de ejemplo para ayudarte?

Comment: gbianchi, actualicé la pregunta agregando el create. Espero sirva.

Comment: o sea que ingreso debe estar entre blo_desde y blo_hasta y ahi empezamos a contar un bloque?

Comment: ¿Y que ocurre si la fecha de selección es `23-03-2017 09:45:00`?

Comment: Exacto, según la fecha de ingreso, se debe ubicar en los bloques y si éstos son continuos se deben seleccionar los 4, pero si hay un hueco entre los números de bloques, sólo se deben seleccionar aquellos bloques entre los que se encuentre la fecha de ingreso.

Comment: Patricio, si esa es la fecha de ingreso, debería seleccionar sólo los bloques 5 y 6.

Comment: Ok, modifiqué mi respuesta en función de los cambios de requerimiento. Saludos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Por empezar te aclaro que no trabajo habitualmente con Oracle, por lo que esta propuesta esta pensada desde mi conocimiento tampoco demasiado extenso en SQL Server.

En primer lugar vamos a crear una tabla de "bloques" que por cada `BLO_NUMERO` tengamos el `BLO_NUMERO` inicial el final y la `BLO_FECHA_HASTA`.

```
CREATE TABLE BLOQUES(
    BLO_NUMERO       NUMBER,
    BLO_NUMERO_DESDE NUMBER,
    BLO_NUMERO_HASTA NUMBER,
    BLO_FECHA_HASTA  DATE
);
```

Y la completaríamos de la siguiente forma:

```
INSERT INTO BLOQUES (BLO_NUMERO, BLO_NUMERO_HASTA, BLO_FECHA_HASTA)
SELECT  T.BLO_NUMERO, MIN(T3.BLO_NUMERO), T.BLO_FECHA_HASTA
    FROM INGRESOS T
    LEFT JOIN (SELECT   T1.BLO_NUMERO,
                T1.BLO_FECHA_HASTA
                    FROM INGRESOS T1
                    LEFT JOIN INGRESOS T2
                        ON T1.BLO_NUMERO = T2.BLO_NUMERO - 1
                WHERE T2.BLO_NUMERO IS NULL
        ) T3
        ON T.BLO_NUMERO <= T3.BLO_NUMERO
    GROUP BY T.BLO_NUMERO, T.BLO_FECHA_HASTA

MERGE
INTO    BLOQUES trg
USING   (
        SELECT  B.BLO_NUMERO, B1.BLO_NUMERO AS BLO_NUMERO_DESDE
    FROM BLOQUES B
    INNER JOIN (SELECT BLO_NUMERO_HASTA, MIN(BLO_NUMERO) BLO_NUMERO
            FROM BLOQUES
            GROUP BY BLO_NUMERO_HASTA
        ) B1
        ON B1.BLO_NUMERO_HASTA = B.BLO_NUMERO_HASTA
        ) src
ON      (trg.BLO_NUMERO = src.BLO_NUMERO)
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE
    SET trg.BLO_NUMERO_DESDE = src.BLO_NUMERO_DESDE;
```

El resultado final es una tabla como la siguiente

```
BLO_NUMERO  BLO_NUMERO_DESDE    BLO_NUMERO_HASTA    BLO_FECHA_HASTA
=========== =================== =================== ====================
1           1                   2                   23-MAR-2017 09:00:00
2           1                   2                   23-MAR-2017 09:40:00
5           5                   6                   23-MAR-2017 12:00:00
6           5                   6                   23-MAR-2017 12:40:00
```

Para ubicar el bloque que necesitamos listar en función de la fecha solicitada vamos a buscar la `BLO_FECHA_HASTA` mínima posterior a la fecha de selección, algo así, creo con ese criterio abarcamos todas las posibilidades (fecha anterior al primer registro, fecha en el medio de un hueco, NO contempla fecha posterior al último registro):

```
SELECT  T.BLO_NUMERO,
        TO_CHAR(T.BLO_FECHA_INGRESO, 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') AS BLO_FECHA_INGRESO,
        T.BLO_DESDE,
        T.BLO_HASTA,
        TO_CHAR(T.BLO_FECHA_HASTA, 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') AS BLO_FECHA_HASTA
    FROM INGRESOS T
    INNER JOIN BLOQUES B
        ON T.BLO_NUMERO = B.BLO_NUMERO
    INNER JOIN (SELECT *
                    FROM  (SELECT   B1.BLO_NUMERO_HASTA,
                MIN(B1.BLO_FECHA_HASTA) AS BLO_FECHA_HASTA
                FROM BLOQUES B1
                WHERE B1.BLO_FECHA_HASTA >= TO_DATE('23/03/2017 08:25:37', 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
                -- WHERE B1.BLO_FECHA_HASTA >= TO_DATE('23/03/2017 11:25:37', 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
                --WHERE B1.BLO_FECHA_HASTA >= TO_DATE('23/03/2017 09:45:37', 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
                GROUP BY B1.BLO_NUMERO_HASTA, B1.BLO_FECHA_HASTA
                ORDER BY B1.BLO_FECHA_HASTA ASC
            ) B3
            WHERE ROWNUM = 1
        ) B2
        ON B2.BLO_NUMERO_HASTA = B.BLO_NUMERO_HASTA;
```

La salida, con una fecha de selección `23/03/2017 08:25:37` sería algo como lo que estarías necesitando:

```
BLO_NUMERO  BLO_FECHA_INGRESO     BLO_DESDE BLO_HASTA   BLO_FECHA_HASTA
=========== ===================== ========= =========== ==================== 
1           23-MAR-2017 08:25:37  08:20:00  09:00:00    23-MAR-2017 09:00:00
2           23-MAR-2017 08:25:37  09:01:00  09:40:00    23-MAR-2017 09:40:00
```

Creo que debiera haber formas mejores de resolverlo, pero por ahora es lo que se me ocurre. Espero te sea útil.

Comment: Hola Patricio. Nuevamente, muchas gracias por la respuesta. Con el código que has puesto, funciona bien para los casos en que hay un "hueco" en los bloques, ya sea ingresando las "08:25", las "11:25" y las "09:45". Pero cuando los bloques son correlativos y por ejemplo la fecha es "23/03/2017 11:25:37", debería haber marcado los últimos 2 bloques, pero marca los 4. Trataré de darle una vuelta a tu código y ver qué debo modificar para lograr eso. Gracias.